# Java Mail is displaying <h2>text

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am new to this community, I am trying to send email through my application mail content  is displaying

```
<h2>New User Request for <FONT style='color:#4649FE;'> Applicaiton </FONT></h1><br/><b>Requested By :
```

It should not display headers , I am using `mail1.4 jar` for mails.

Comment: you should go through http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting...

Comment: Do you want to display html content in mail body??

Comment: First off, you spelled `Application` wrong. Also the mixing of uppercase and lowercase tags is annoying to some people (I'm fine with it, but prefer lowercase, however, your dev team may not be so cool). You seem to be using HTML4 also, I'd suggest switching to HTML5 just to make it look better.

Comment: Sorry Cole Johnson as i am using it in firsttime this i will learn how to post soon

Answer (score 2):

You have an open `<h2>`, but you have a closing `</h1>`.

Try changing it to the same tag.

Comment: yes i want to display html content in mail body the content should display 
New User Request in headers with blue color and so

Comment: Sorry Cole Johnson as i am using it in firsttime this  i will learn how to post soon

Comment: @user1605984 your tags mismatch.